# How to make fireworks in Python using turtle

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm very new to python, and am trying to make an endless animated fireworks display in the background for something I'm making using turtle, but don't know how to make it animated(that is, to make them explode outward, then disappear), and I need help with making it go on endlessly. Please help!
Here's my current code:

```
import random
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)

#firework color
def pen(color):
    t.color(color)

pen('red')

def move():
    t.pu()
    x = random.randint(-165,165)
    y = random.randint(-165,165)
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.pd()

def sky(colour):
     wn = turtle.Screen()
     wn.bgcolor(colour)

sky('black')

def firework(size):
    for num in range (20):
         t.fd(size)
         t.rt(180-(360/20))

firework(50)
move()
pen('yellow')
firework(75)
move()

pen('orange')
firework(199)   
firework(50)
move()

pen('blue')
firework(75)
move()

pen('pink')
firework(199)
firework(50)
move()

pen('yellow')
firework(75)
move()

pen('orange')
firework(199)   
firework(50)
move()

pen('blue')
firework(75)
move()

pen('pink')
firework(199)
firework(50)
move()

pen('yellow')
firework(75)
move()

pen('orange')
firework(199)   
firework(50)
move()
pen('blue')
firework(75)
move()

pen('pink')
firework(199)
firework(50)
move()

pen('yellow')
firework(75)
move()

pen('orange')
firework(199)   
firework(50)
move()

pen('blue')
firework(75)
move()

pen('pink')
firework(199)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can clear the drawing using `t.clear()`, which will clear the entire drawing. The problem is that your code is formatted kinda messily, so I'll assume you want a disappear for every blank line you have.

```
import random
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)

def pen(color):
    t.color(color)

pen('red')

def move():
    t.pu()
    x = random.randint(-165,165)
    y = random.randint(-165,165)
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.pd()

def sky(colour):
     wn = turtle.Screen()
     wn.bgcolor(colour)

sky('#10102a')

def firework(size):
    for num in range(20):
         t.fd(size)
         t.rt(180-(360/20))

# Begin Config #
C_BRIGHT_MIN = 0x10
C_BRIGHT_MAX = 0xef
F_SIZE_MIN = 15
F_SIZE_MAX = 200
FIREWORK_PER_CLEAR = 2
# End Config #

while True:
    # this generates a random color sequence using RGB
    color_r = hex(random.randint(C_BRIGHT_MIN, C_BRIGHT_MAX))[2:]
    color_g = hex(random.randint(C_BRIGHT_MIN, C_BRIGHT_MAX))[2:]
    color_b = hex(random.randint(C_BRIGHT_MIN, C_BRIGHT_MAX))[2:]
    pen('#'+color_r+color_g+color_b)
    for i in range(FIREWORK_PER_CLEAR):
        firework(random.randint(F_SIZE_MIN, F_SIZE_MAX))
        move()
    t.clear()
```

It doesn't "explode out", if you want it to be like that you can try `tkinter` or `pygame` which is a lot more optimized for graphics

Comment: Could you try making the code go on endlessly, and have the fireworks not overlap as well? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Because I don't know what you wanted I put a config there C_BRIGHT_MIN and C_BRIGHT_MAX is the range of colors that can be used, avoiding the two ends of the color spectrum. F_SIZE_MIN and F_SIZE_MAX are the two bounds of the sizes of the fireworks. FIREWORK_PER_CLEAR is how many before they disappear.